# Logout is not working in multi auth in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes

I have implemented multi auth in app and everything is working fine except admin logout. I am trying to protect the admin.logout route using except() method but it is not working, executing the guest middleware and redirecting to the dashboard. Saw the route list and admin.logout route has still guest:admin middleware. I am trying to logout admin from adminLogout method controller function in AdminLoginController but it is not logging out admin. here are the pictures of my code. So how to resolve this admin logout issue?

**auth.php**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
        'admin-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ]
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

**Web.php**

```
//login routes for users
Route::get('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// routes for admin
Route::prefix('admin')->namespace('Admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@adminLogin');
    Route::post('logout', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@adminLogout')->name('adminlogout');
    Route::post('hello', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@hello')->name('adminHello');

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin']], function(){
        Route::get('setting', 'AdminController@adminSetting');
        Route::get('dashboard', 'AdminController@adminDashboard')->name('admin.dashboard');
        Route::get('customers', 'AdminController@customers');
    });
});
```

**AdminLoginController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use App\Admin;

class AdminLoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('adminlogout');
    }

    public function showLoginForm(){
        return view('auth.admin.adminLogin');
    }

    public function adminLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email'   => 'required|email|exists:admins',
            'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ]);
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'))) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();

            return redirect()->intended('/admin/dashboard');
        }
        return back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
    }
    public function adminLogout(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::guard('admin')->logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        return redirect('/admin/login');
    }
}
```

when I see all the routes list using *php artisan route:list*, it is showing me this 
[image]

*admin/logout* route has still guest:admin middleware and it is not protecting my admin/logout route from guest:admin middleware and executing *RedirectIfAuthenticated* middleware even I put this route in except() method in AdminLoginController.
Kindly resolve how to logout from admin?

Comment: Run following commands:
`php artisan cache:clear`
`php artisan route:clear`
`php artisan config:clear`
`php artisan view:clear`

Comment: @utdev already did that but still there is guest:admin on the logout route..